# Apache Camel, sFTP component and idempotent repository

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I want to build application in high availability (HA) mode.
This means I can have changeable number of instances i.e. I need to have 5 instances of application.
The application should read data from ftp/sftp, avoiding duplicates (one file can't be process 2 times).
To resolve this problem I decide to use clustered camel routes in `active/active` setup. This setup is using Idempotent repository.

Below is my Idempotent Repository Configuration (I'm using spring boot, and camel spring boot starters, sql and ftp)

```java
@Configuration
public class IdempotentRepoConf {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcMessageIdRepository sftpProcesorName() {
        return new JdbcMessageIdRepository(dataSource, "sftpProcesorName");
    }

}
```

And my Router

```java
@Component
public class FooSftpRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private IdempotentRepository idempotentRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("sftp:localhost:2221/upload/files/foo?username=foo" +
                "&password=pass" +
                "&move=./.done" +
                "&moveFailed=.error" +
                "&idempotentRepository=#sftpProcesorName")
                .idempotentConsumer(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME),idempotentRepository)
                    .to("sftp:localhost:2221/upload/files/bar?username=foo&password=pass")
                .end();

    }
}
```

When I run just one instance everything is working without any problem, but when I run more than one instance I have problem with error

```
2020-08-03 15:14:14.589  WARN 18071 --- [pload/files/foo] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpConsumer         : Error processing file RemoteFile[Foo 4 ] due to Cannot retrieve file: upload/files/foo/Foo 4 . Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot retrieve file: upload/files/foo/Foo 4 ]

org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot retrieve file: upload/files/foo/Foo 4 
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFileToStreamInBody(SftpOperations.java:778) ~[camel-ftp-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFile(SftpOperations.java:717) ~[camel-ftp-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:434) ~[camel-file-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:145) ~[camel-ftp-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:234) ~[camel-file-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:196) ~[camel-file-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187) ~[camel-support-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:106) ~[camel-support-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: No such file
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2225) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1318) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1290) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFileToStreamInBody(SftpOperations.java:759) ~[camel-ftp-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

To receive this warrning I do these steps

1. Place several files in sftp in localization `/home/foo/upload/files/foo` (i.e.

```sh
for i in {1..10}; do  touch "Foo $i "; done;
```

2. Check database (postgress)

```sql
select * from camel_messageprocessed;
```

and as I expected I have 10 records

```
  processorname   | messageid |        createdat        
------------------+-----------+-------------------------
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 1     | 2020-08-03 15:14:13.392
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 10    | 2020-08-03 15:14:13.607
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 9     | 2020-08-03 15:14:14.409
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 6     | 2020-08-03 15:14:14.419
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 8     | 2020-08-03 15:14:14.427
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 2     | 2020-08-03 15:14:14.435
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 3     | 2020-08-03 15:14:14.447
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 5     | 2020-08-03 15:14:14.455
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 4     | 2020-08-03 15:14:14.462
 sftpProcesorName | Foo 7     | 2020-08-03 15:14:14.469
(10 rows)
```

but in logs I see Warn and errors multiple time

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot retrieve file: upload/files/foo/Foo 3
```

and

```
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: No such file
```

My build.gradle have dependency

```
    compile 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-ftp-starter:3.2.0'
    compile 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-sql-starter:3.2.0'
```

I also tried with option `readLock=idempotent`  but this option in [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sftp-component.html) is `(only for file component)`   and probably don't work in ftp/sftp component

So my problem to avoid duplication and process only one time is still not resolved.

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Clearly your processes are competing. I don't think this is doing anything

`&idempotentRepository=#sftpProcesorName`

and the `idempotentConsumer()` DSL is operating only after SFTP has occurred.

Some items to try from memory:

- `readLock=fileLock` # probably wont work
- `readlock=markerFile` # might be all you need for "mostly ok" operation
- `inProgressRepository=#jdbcRepository` Should be iron-clad solution.

Comment: @Michal Can you please advise what solved this issue for you?